# Closing as unclear to give way to another post?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/225547/) is closed as unclear by 5 users given no comment reason. In sandbox there's also no more discussion but IO format.

The only possiblility I see is to give way another question. Either because hate me or hate the IO or hate my word, it seems a bad idea. It's even more silly to claim it unclear because it doesn't expilictly say standard loopholes apply.

What to do? Or is it only solution to stop asking in sandbox?

Standard loopholes apply, including no Internet, so I won't be pushed here and there to "discuss".

Answer (score 8):

The close reason is simple. You need details and clarity. There is no reason beyond that to close your question.

Here's a few things you can improve, to be specific:

- You require a clear description of what an uncomputable number is, and maybe link to it. A single line description is not enough, and having more examples would help with understanding the concept. Having your question be mostly self-contained is important.
- If you are finding it hard to phrase your question in English, you can link your question in [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte). There's many people willing to help with that. People have to take time out of their day to browse the sandbox, and they are bound to miss some questions, so it is almost necessary to ask in chat to get proper feedback.
- There is no clear description of I/O in the question. In your question, I am not sure if I am required to take input. The example code does not seem to be in a specific language, so it cannot be run in order to figure out the correct output either. Borrowing from questions under the same topic ([number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) for example) helps a lot, and having working, usable example code generally works in your question's favour.
- Only one person(Bubbler) has commented on your post, and your post also has 0 votes. Votes imply approval of your post, so checking votes is important, and I recommend having at least 3 people comment and discuss about your question in the sandbox before submitting it to the main site.

Comment: 1. As mentioned(later deleted) there'd be a bottom of `know` or otherwise someone can keep asking definition of everything. 2. It's bad if asking require asking before that much. 3. [Standard Loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1789/) 4. so the result is still Stop Asking in Sandbox(and also main)?

Comment: @l4m2 You should make an effort to explain anything in your question that would require the average code golfer to go to a separate page and google it, aside from challenges which rely on familiarity with a broader topic (like calculus). For (2), it's not optimal for people to have to ask in TNB for more feedback, but at the moment it's the best option. Not doing that is likely going to result in your draft not receiving enough feedback, especially for more specific things you want addressed. For (3), the loophole you link to is unrelated to this entirely.